# Meteor Change password template

Tags: meteor-autoform

I want to provide user to view password in clear text in change password form which is generated by meteor can please somebody help me on this ?

i tried using texts.inputicons.current_password it did not work kept give me error did not match. it was in

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Autoform is a very extensively package that you can create your own input type. See here: https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform?tab=readme-ov-file#defining-custom-input-types with your own HTML, JS and CSS.